# Trying to get Sprite to work - css

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

Just trying to get a very simple sprite to work: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pZgr3/)

What I am trying to do is toggle between the "set" and "unset" bold/italic icons which are in the first and second row of my sprite (respectively).

```
<a id="bold" class="disabled"></a>      
<a id="italic"></a>
```

Code seems to be ignoring the "disabled" class as I would expect the bold to be unset (ie have a white background with black text).

Can anybody see what I have done wrong?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mentioned `#bold .disabled` which means an element with class `disabled` inside an element with id `bold`.

It should be `#bold.disabled` as its the id and the class for the same element

```css
#bold.disabled {
   background-position: 0 -29px;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/pZgr3/1/)